# How to get rid of TypeScript error in Puppeteer eval?

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I have a simple puppeteer script:

```
export async function inspectWebpage(source) {
  const b = await getBrowser()
  const p = await b.newPage()
  await p.goto(path)
  const script = fs.readFileSync(
    'host/code/node/puppeteer/crawl.js',
    'utf-8',
  )
  await p.evaluate(script)
  let data = await p.evaluate(() => task.getWebpageData())
  await b.close()
  return data
}
```

I am seeing this though each time I use it, and would like to get rid of it.

```
Cannot find name 'task'.ts(2304)
```

[image]

The `task` object is what I exported globally from a webpack build, to get that `script` into puppeteer's context.

Similar situation with trying to access things on the puppeteer `window`, like `window.X.y` gives me:

```
Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

So how do I add type annotations in this spot? What if my script wanted to access a global variable I injected, that sort of stuff.

Comment: `p.evaluate("task.getWebpageData")` should work.

Comment: Is there no better way? Then I don't get TypeScript hinting, but I guess I can limit the API to just that one call there, and have the script itself be TypeScript compiled to webpack. Looks like parentheses needed too `p.evaluate("task.getWebpageData()")`

Comment: There may be a better way, just getting you unblocked. It's a good question. Of course `// @ts-ignore` on the line is another workaround. As an aside, rather than `readFileSync` and `evaluate` on the script, there's `page.addScriptTag` which is a bit easier. I'd also put `b.close()` in a `finally` block so it closes in case there's a throw.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried addScriptTag in the past but had trouble with it, will try again.

Comment: @ggorlen when I do `await p.addScriptTag({ path: 'host/code/node/puppeteer/theme.js' })` I get `task is not defined` when it calls evaluate.

Comment: Weird, I guess I'd have to see an example to debug that. Not a big deal though, I understand it's tangent to your main question. Feel free to open another question if you do want to work that out though.